# I think there are leftovers from previous OS X versions on my HD, how can I find/delete those?

Tags: macos, mac

I've got two Macs, one of them is a few versions newer than the other. They are both currently running the latest version, but the older Mac has **lots** of OS and system files that the newer one hasn't

Comment: the Mac's are not the same? so in order to support the older system additional files were installed. Look for the installation date of the files.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD For some reason, no. Well I could sort them by date and delete them accordingly, but that would be a pain as there is loads of them...

Answer (score 1):

I did a search using the following keywords: mac remove old version

The most promising result [described three applications](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/three-apps-for-cleaning-older-mac-installs/) that could work for you.

I suppose that backing up to Time Machine, doing a clean install, and then restoring from Time Machine wouldn't work. The backup would include all the garbage files that you were seeking to be rid of.

Maybe it would be doable to do a clean install, but then only restore selected applications from the backup?

Comment: Could be. Though I think I'm going to partition my HD, then wipe one of the partitions and reinstall the latest OS X version, and then on the other partition I'd save my most important stuff－I was thinking if keeping the .plist files would save my preferences when booting from the newly installed OS X version, hmm...